# Requesting model data from network

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtcpsocket, qabstracttablemodel, qdatastream

When in model methods `rowCount()` and `columnCount()` I try to retrieve data from server using `QTcpSocket`, the model calls these methods few times but not calls `data()` afterwards. The associated `QTableView` displays nothing. I checked with debugger and it shows that `rowCount()` and `columnCount()` are returning valid data.

The model is derived from `QAbstractTableModel`. Here's the code of `TcpTableModel::rowCount()`:

```
//Setup waiting for server response
QTimer timer;
timer.setSingleShot(true);
QEventLoop eventLoop;
connect(&m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, &eventLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &eventLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
timer.start(TIMEOUT);

//Using QDataStream to send and receive model information
QDataStream dataStream(&m_tcpSocket);
dataStream << MSG_REQUEST_ROWS_COUNT;//Sending request for number of rows
eventLoop.exec();

//If no response received
if(!timer.isActive())
{
    connect(&m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &TcpTableModel::readyRead);
    return 0;
}
timer.stop();

//Receiving information from server
dataStream.startTransaction();
int msgType = -1;
int rowCount = -1;
dataStream >> msgType;
dataStream >> rowCount;
if((msgType != MSG_REQUEST_ROWS_COUNT) || (rowCount == -1))
{
    dataStream.commitTransaction();
    return 0;
}
dataStream.commitTransaction();

return rowCount;
```

The server uses same approach to process the request. It receives `MSG_REQUEST_ROWS_COUNT` and then sends back `MSG_REQUEST_ROWS_COUNT` and an int containing the number of rows.

What could be the source of such behavior in my program? Maybe `QTableView` can't work properly if its requests to model are satisfied with delay. Or maybe I should use completely different approach to get model data from server?

Comment: Are you able to use `QTableView` with an offline model?

Comment: Yes, with offline model it works well. If I use container placed in model (instead of request to server) it works fine.

Comment: I guess that your method sometimes returns `0`. If you change your model, i.e. when your return 0 now because the data is not yet read and process the tcp request in `TcpTableModel::readyRead` later, you should call [`beginInsertRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) and [`endInsertRows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows) to notify the views that your model is changed. Note that it may be better to always send your requests asynchronously.

Comment: [`fetchMore`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) may be interesting in your situation.